# docker container fails to create because of volume

Tags: sql-server, macos, docker, macos-big-sur

I have the following docker compose file:

```
version: "3.6"
services:
  db:
    image: "mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server"
    user: root
    environment:
      SA_PASSWORD: "supersecure"
      ACCEPT_EULA: 'y'
    ports:
      - "1433:1433"
    volumes:
      - ./db:/var/opt/mssql
volumes: 
  db:
    driver: local
```

When I try to run it, it fails and the following logs are what I see via Docker Desktop:

```
Attaching to server_db_1

db_1 | SQL Server 2019 will run as non-root by default.

db_1 | This container is running as user root.

db_1 | Your master database file is owned by root.

db_1 | To learn more visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2099216.

db_1 | This program has encountered a fatal error and cannot continue running at Tue Mar 30 14:33:43 2021

db_1 | The following diagnostic information is available:

db_1 |

db_1 | Reason: 0x00000007

db_1 | Status: 0xc000014c

db_1 | Message: Corruption detected in persistent registry: \SystemRoot\lsvcid.hiv.

db_1 | Stack Trace:

db_1 | file://package4/windows/system32/sqlpal.dll+0x000000000029776C

db_1 | file://package4/windows/system32/sqlpal.dll+0x0000000000296A50

db_1 | file://package4/windows/system32/sqlpal.dll+0x000000000029462C

db_1 | file://package4/windows/system32/sqlpal.dll+0x0000000000294804

db_1 | file://package4/windows/system32/sqlpal.dll+0x0000000000293660

db_1 | file://package4/windows/system32/sqlpal.dll+0x0000000000292170

db_1 | file://package4/windows/system32/sqlpal.dll+0x00000000003543B1

db_1 | Process: 11 - sqlservr

db_1 | Thread: 15 (application thread 0x4)

db_1 | Instance Id: 461256be-50fe-44ca-8448-e871abce60a6

db_1 | Crash Id: b59e1c31-56bd-4c32-83bb-1589cc4ae460

db_1 | Build stamp: 8c201b336a2d5ea8f32b4655d414097e63db40c5a3bda5d146d8f480ca292e60

db_1 | Distribution: Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS

db_1 | Processors: 6

db_1 | Total Memory: 8351440896 bytes

db_1 | Timestamp: Tue Mar 30 14:33:43 2021

db_1 | Last errno: 19

db_1 | Last errno text: No such device

db_1 |
```

After it dies, I see that it has created the volume:

```
admins-Mac-mini-3:server admin$ docker volume ls
DRIVER    VOLUME NAME
local     server_db
admins-Mac-mini-3:server admin$
```

When I try to create the container without the volume, it works just fine.  But I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You're creating an empty named volume, but you're mounting a host directory `./db` into the container.  Do you mean to mount the named volume, `db:/var/opt/mssql`, without the `./db` relative path?

Comment: So we have database scripts that will run to create data... once the container is created.  And they do want us to use a relative path...relative to where the docker-compose file lives.  Does that help / make sense?

Comment: Those scripts don't need to be stored in the database's data directory, though, do they?  Can you launch them from the host, or another container, or as part of your application's database migrations?

Comment: actually i think that's what we're doing (this isn't my code.  just trying to get it working locally). I think the idea is that a vstudio project runs ... creates some sql migration scripts in the db folder on the host ... and that's mounted into the container and the migrations on run on the container.  does that make sense?